# Why isn't Countifs working with more than 2 criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

Im generating a report and using countifs function to get matching values for various parts. However every time that I use all the criteria it doesn't work. It throws a "Run time error 1004" Unable to get the CountIfs property of the WorksheetFunction class.

The same format was copied from a previous countifs that I wrote previously that works. I have tried adding in the criteria one by one to see where  it threw the error and it threw it after the 3rd criteria was added.

I've checked several answers on here that seem to say something like the countifs can't work on a disconnected range but I don't believe this is disconnected unless I'm missing something to the definition of that.

P.S. excel is in German as well

```
wsPull.Cells(RowsBW, 16)), wsBackground.Cells(c.Row, 3), _
                     wsPull.Range(wsPull.Cells(2, 14), wsPull.Cells(RowsBW, 14)), "2nd", _
                     wsPull.Range(wsPull.Cells(2, 21), wsPull.Cells(RowsAB, 21)), "3rd", _
                     wsPull.Range(wsPull.Cells(2, 24), wsPull.Cells(RowsBW, 24)), "4th")
```

Notes on the code c.row is based on the row of the found value and needs to be there for the code to run. RowsBW represents the number of rows in the wsPull worksheet.

The code is a part of a loop that gets the first search criteria based on the value of the i iteration.

Comment: Can you add the whole formula? There's data missing here.

Comment: What about the data that 3rd one tests?

Comment: What's `SAPBWZieh`? Is `RowsAD` the same number as `RowsBW`?

Comment: In all functions type COUNTIFS, SUMIFS and so on, all criteria ranges must be same size (must contain same number of cells). Are all those ranges same size?

Comment: I will Update the code. To answer the other questions @SolarMike I don't understand the question.

Comment: You stated it failed after the 3rd criteria was added, so check the data or criteria for that 3rd one - must be where the error is as it was fine for the first two...

Comment: @rory my mistake thought I got it all SAPBWZieh is wsPull. Good catch on RowsBW RowsAB that might actually be why. I changed variable names for the question to be a bit easier to follow. foxfire I don't see why they wouldn't be the same size. All are on the same worksheet and the range is just the respective columns from the 2nd row to the last row.

Comment: @rory That was the issue thanks a lot was staring at the code for two long only seeing what I expected it to be. Now to figure out the other errors :)